# Python + selenium: extract variable quantity of paragraphs between titles

Tags: python, html, selenium, beautifulsoup, urllib2

Fellows, assuming the html below how can extract the paragraphs `<p>` who belongs to the tile `<h3>`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    ...
        <div class="main-div">
            <h3>Title 1</h3>
            <p></p>
        
            <h3>Title 2</h3>
            <p></p>
            <p></p>
            <p></p>
            
            <h3>Title 3</h3>
            <p></p>
            <p></p>
            ...
        </div>
</body>
```

As you can see both `<h3>` and `<p>` tags are children of the `<div>` tag **but they have no class or id** that makes possible to identify them and say that "Title 1" has 1 paragraph, title 2 has 3 paragraphs, title 3 has two paragraphs and so on. I can't see a way to tie the paragraph to the title...

**I'm trying to do it using Python 2.7 + selenium**. But I'm not sure that I'm working with the right tools, maybe you can suggest the solution or any different combinations like Beautifulsoup, urllib2...

Any suggestion/direction will be very appreciated!

---

## UPDATE

After the brilliant solution pointed by @JustMe I came up with the solution below, hope it helps someone else or if someone can improve it to pythonic. I coming from c/c++/java/perl world so always I hit the wall :)

```
import bs4

page = """ 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
...
    <div class="maincontent-block">
        <h3>Title 1</h3>
        <p>1</p>
        <p>2</p>
        <p>3</p>

        <h3>Title 2</h3>
        <p>2</p>
        <p>3</p>
        <p>4</p>

        <h3>Title 3</h3>
        <p>7</p>
        <p>9</p>
        ...
    </div>
</body>
"""

page = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
div = page.find('div', {'class':"maincontent-block"})

mydict = {}

# write to the dictionary
for tag in div.findChildren():
    if (tag.name == "h3"):
        #print(tag.string)
        mydict[tag.string] = None
        nextTags = tag.findAllNext()
        arr = [];
        for nt in nextTags:
            if (nt.name == "p"):
                arr.append(nt.string)
                mydict[tag.string] = arr
            elif (nt.name == "h3"):
                arr = []
                break

# read from dictionary
arrKeys = []
for k in mydict:
    arrKeys.append(k)

arrKeys.sort()
for k in arrKeys:
    print k
    for v in mydict[k]:
        print v
```

Comment: your answer has nothing to do with selenium.. update the question's title and tags.

Comment: I would like to do it with selenium but I couldn't accomplish it, so the question remains the same. Maybe someone can come by and drop one or two lines with the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy to be done using BeautifulSoup

```
import bs4

page = """
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    ...
        <div class="main-div">
            <h3>Title 1</h3>
            <p></p>

            <h3>Title 2</h3>
            <p></p>
            <p></p>
            <p></p>

            <h3>Title 3</h3>
            <p></p>
            <p></p>
            ...
        </div>
</body>
"""

page = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page)
h3_tag = page.div.find("h3").string
print(h3_tag)
>>> u'Title 1'

h3_tag.find_next_siblings("p")
>>> [<p></p>, <p></p>, <p></p>, <p></p>, <p></p>, <p></p>]
len(h3_tag.find_next_siblings("p"))/2
>>> 3
```

Ok, since You want separated count of paragraphs i came up with this, crude thing.

```
 h_counters = []
 count = -1
 for child in page.div.findChildren():
     if "<h3>" in str(child):
         h_counters.append(count)
         count = 0
     else:
         count += 1
 h_counters.append(count)
 h_counters = h_counters[1:]
 print (h_counters)
 >> [1, 3, 2]
```

Comment: It is a good solution but this is exactly where I am. I'm looking for some solution where I can associate the paragraph below the Title 1 to the title 1, after that associate the three paragraphs below the Title 2 to the title 2 and so on.

As `<p>` are not children of the `<h3>` and h3 has no id to identify it, I don't see how I can accomplish it.

Comment: I've edited my answer, does that help ? Hm, no, wait You wanted  just one. Let me see.

Comment: No, you're right! We are almost there. I'm looking for a way to say something like: these paragraphs belongs to this title. As the quantity of paragraphs are variable regardless the title it is hard to accomplish it. I've tried the find_next_siblings("p") thanks for that by the way, but it returns all paragraphs. Maybe we can call findNext() and test each result against `<p>` or `<h3>`, what to you think?

Comment: I've read somewhat through  documentation and didn't find anything nice...so came up with iterative method...not so pretty i guess, but hey, it's working at least ;)

Comment: AMAZING! Thank you buddy, hope one day I can help you somehow.